# Tortoise SVN "is out of date" and "update copy first" errors

Tags: svn, tortoisesvn

I have checked it out more but did not find a clear answer for my issue about **is out of date** and **You have to update your copy first** errors in Tortoise SVN.

Just i want to go revision X and make some changes in my software code. Then, i want to commit it for new version. However, this error window appears.

Can you help me to solve this issue?

[Picture: Error window in Tortoise SVN](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rUyx7.png)

Answer (score 0):

1. Patching old code is always **The Bad Idea (tm)** - you'll get a lot of headaches with forward-porting results into `current` codebase
2. You must read and *understand* SVN Book chapters about branching and merging before starting a patch-trip

If you can't commit from outdated WC to repo, you have to have path in repo with *the same verson*, as you want to modify

In order to get it, you can|have:

- Update your WC to `<OLDREV>` (done)
- Create new branch in repo from your WC
- Hack-commit-debug code to branch
- When you finished patching, try to merge (`merge ...--dry-run`) trunk to your branch (in order to integrate changes of historic code into current codebase), get "Merge Hell", resolve all conflicts
- Debug resulting code-mix in branch, get it in OK-state
- Merge branch back to trunk